# How to use the page URL as a variable in a php function that decides which image to load from /images depending on the URL

Tags: php, image, url, variables

I have a friend who has registered a URL for every county where i'm from. All of the urls point to one webspace. I want to use the page url in a php/js function to load the holding image corresponding to that url So what i need is

```
if ($url = www.url1.com){

print(img src="images/url1.png )

}

else if ($url2 - www.url2.com){

print(img src ="images/url2.png )

}
```

And so on. Each url is completely different, so I can't use different paths. I don't know how to use the pages url as a variable.
 I'm quite new to this stuff so apologies if this is ridiculously simple. Also, let me know if I haven't been detailed enough, I know that's annoying. Thanks in advance!

STILL NOT WORKING, HERE'S MY CODE, ANY HELP WOULD BE GREATLY APPRECIATED,,,

```
 <?php
```

$_SERVER['HTTP_POST'];

```
            if ($_SERVER = "http://www.carlowataclick.com/")
                 {
                         print ("<img src = images/carlowataclick.png />");


                 };

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is probably your best bet. That's the name of the site/host as provided by the user in the URL they entered/clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to check the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'] to see where they came from. Although, some browsers do not have the referrer, and this can't be reliable.

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'];

if ($url = www.url1.com){

print(img src="images/url1.png )

}
```

EDIT: HTTP_HOST. (from guy below me)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you run `print_r($_SERVER)` on your script and look into the output of that array. You'll find your URL in one of the elements of that array, perhaps $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] is the one you'll need.

```
switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'www.url1.com':
        // print image 1;
        break;
    case 'www.url2.com':
        // print image 2;
        break;
}
```

I think you do not need to give http:// because $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] does not contain it, but please verify it.